# How to display different title depends on action?

Tags: java, html

I have got two methods that redirect to the same `.html` file.
First method is method responsible for saving, the second method is for updating.
It has got the same view so I just wanted to move user to the same view.
I have `<h1>..</h1>` in `.html` I would like to have title `"New Mapping"` for adding new mapping and `"Update mapping"` when we want to update mapping.
These are methods that do all the stuff (redirecting to the .html file)

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/.../update", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String updatePage(@RequestParam("...") String ..., Model model) {
        String[] tokens = ....split("_");
        Template template= class.method(...);
        model.addAttribute("template", template);
        return "save";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/.../save")
    public String newMappingPage(Model model) {
        Template template = new Template();
        template.setCostIndex("10");
        model.addAttribute("template", template);
        return "save";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/.../save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveMapping(@ModelAttribute Template template) {
        class.method(template);
        return "redirect:/main-page";
    }
```

`save.hml` file

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Engine</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/file.css}"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>New/Update mapping</h1>
<form action="save" method="post" th:object="${template}">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="...">....[min]</label>
        <input type="number" id="..." th:field="*{...}" step="0.1" min="0"/>
        <label for="...">...</label>
        <input type="number" id="...." th:field="*{...}" required="true"/>
        <label for="...">....</label>
        <input type="text" id="..." th:field="*{...}" maxlength="1024" size="50"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label for="response">Response</label>
        <br/>
        <textarea id="response" rows="20" cols="150" th:field="*{...}" required="true"/>
        <br/>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" class="primary" value="Submit"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the URL contain update or save? or do you want to do this on the server only?

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any such destructive edits will be reverted. Please see [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) for more information on how deleting content works on this site.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create two separate methods for add and update as you are storing data into DB from JSP page. use only one /save API.

```
@PostMapping(path = "/.../{}/save")
public String newMappingPage(Model model) {
  Template template = new Template();
  template.setCostIndex("10");
  model = new Model();
  if (model.getId() > 0) {
    model = findById(model.getId());
    model.addAttribute("heading", "Update Mapping");
  } else {
    model.addAttribute("heading", "New Mapping");
  } 
  //Call method to store data from jsp file 
  return "save";
}
```

In JSP :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Engine</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/file.css}"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>${heading}</h1>
<form action="save" method="post" th:object="${template}">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="...">....[min]</label>
        <input type="number" id="..." th:field="*{...}" step="0.1" min="0"/>
        <label for="...">...</label>
        <input type="number" id="...." th:field="*{...}" required="true"/>
        <label for="...">....</label>
        <input type="text" id="..." th:field="*{...}" maxlength="1024" size="50"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label for="response">Response</label>
        <br/>
        <textarea id="response" rows="20" cols="150" th:field="*{...}" required="true"/>
        <br/>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" class="primary" value="Submit"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your method like this:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/.../{}/save")
public ModelAndView save(Model model) {
  ModelAndView obj = new ModelAndView("save");
  model = new Model();
  if (model.getId() > 0) {
    model = findById(model.getId());
    obj .addAttribute("heading", "Update Mapping");
  } else {
    obj .addAttribute("heading", "New Mapping");
  } 
  //Call method to store data from jsp file 
  return obj;
}
```